# JSF switching image

Tags: jsf, tags, icefaces

This is a follow-up to question [Using <c:when> with an enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093861/using-cwhen-with-an-enumeration)

After following the suggestion from the accepted answer, I encountered another problem. The real image path (my code was example code) is partially generated using a library function to get a themed image path. Please understand that I'm not allowed to disclose real code, so I have to cut lots of pieces when I post here.

The first problem is that h:graphicImage automatically generates an absolute image path for the img tag using the current portlet's path. Example: I need http://myserver/mytheme/portlet/image.gif but if I use `<h:graphicsImage value="#{myNs:getThemePath()}image.gif" />` it gets rendered as http://myserver/**myportlet**/mytheme/portlet/image.gif; instead, using `<img src="#{myNs:getThemePath()}image.gif" />` works perfectly.

As specified in the other question, I need to switch between images basing on a condition of an iterating item in an ICEFaces table, **AND** I also need (for accessibility reasons) to place a correct `alt` attribute with a localized resource.

Briefly, my code resembles the following (`ice:dataTable` omitted)

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <ice:outputText value="#{myNs:getLocale('state')}" />
    </f:facet>
    <img alt="[[TODO]]" src="#{myNs:getThemePath()}#{item.state == 'COMPLETED' ? 'ok' : 'ko'}.gif"
</h:column>
```

The src part works, but now come the problems.

If I use `alt="#myNs:getLocale('prefix.#{item.state = 'COMPLETED' ? 'completed' : 'canceled'}')}` I can't nest expressions (it doesn't get evaluated)

If I create two `<h:graphicsImage` tags for the two cases (no need to use complex expressions in `alt`) and use the `rendered` attribute as described in the other question's accepted answer, I don't get the image URL rendered correctly.

I also can't use the `<c:when` tag because, as explained in the other question, it gets always evaluated to false.

What can I do to meet both requirements? How can I use two `<img` tags and switch their rendering according to my condition?

Thanks

[add] Fortunately, I got the following exception message on Tomcat logs when combining expression . Can somebody help me learn EL expressions better? I'm totally new to JSF

```
Caused by: org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered "#" at line 1, column 32.
Was expecting one of:
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    "null" ...
    "(" ...
    "!" ...
    "not" ...
    "empty" ...
    "-" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <FUNCTION_CALL> ...
```

Comment: "I don't get the image URL rendered correctly." and how do you get it rendered?

Comment: I already said, http://myserver/myportlet/mytheme/portlet/image.gif where the myportlet part of the URL should not be present. Anyway, i finally solved the issue using img tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I solved it by myself in 10 minutes. Let me share how.

A combined expression is feasible, but simply needs no #{} again!!!! What a dumb (did I say I'm a total beginner?)

```
#{item.state = 'COMPLETED' ? myNs:getLocale('prefix.completed') myNs:getLocale('prefix.canceled')}
```

works

Answer (score 5):

To answer the *concrete* question of the ability to render plain vanilla HTML conditionally; just wrap them in a JSF component which supports the `rendered` attribute but does by itself output nothing.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{item.state == 'COMPLETED'}">
    <img src="ok.gif" />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{item.state == 'CANCELLED'}">
    <img src="ko.gif" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

You can also use `<ui:fragment>` instead when you're using Facelets. It has a bit less overhead.

Comment: Great answer!! I'll surely try this the next time!!