# JSTL <c:if> tag not working in JSF 1.1

Tags: jsp, jsf, jstl, tomahawk

I am using JSF 1.1 and Tomahawk and Tomcat 6.0

```
<c:if test="${vo.type=1}">
    <t:commandLink action="#{Manager.openPatient}">
        <c:out value="${vo.patientId}"></c:out>
        <t:outputText value="#{vo.patientId}" />
        <f:param value="#{vo.id}" name="patientId"/>
    </t:commandLink>
</c:if>
```

I am trying to add conditions based on the type. 
If `vo.type = 1` do call Patient.
If `vo.type = 2` do call Account and so on.

It seems that `<c:if>` tag is not working. Any ideas or pointers in resolving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like as in normal Java, you need to compare with `==`, not with `=`.

```
<c:if test="${vo.type == 1}">
```

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, if the same functionality is achievable with pure JSF, then you should prefer that over using JSTL. In this particular case, you could just make use of the `rendered` attribute which is supported by every JSF HTML component. Get rid of `<c:if>` (and the superfluous `<c:out>`) and change the `<t:commandLink>` as follows:

```
<t:commandLink action="#{Manager.openPatient}" rendered="#{vo.type == 1}">
    <t:outputText value="#{vo.patientId}" />
    <f:param value="#{vo.id}" name="patientId"/>
</t:commandLink>
```

Comment: thanks for the inputs there was a typo in "=" while posting it is actually "==" only in the code I would check the rendered tag now and would update you .. I am pretty sure this would work

Comment: Then the concrete problem was caused by something else. My cents on that you have this in a datatable. Then JSTL won't work at all. Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093861/using-cwhen-with-an-enumeration/5094100#5094100) which I posted yesterday for more detail.

Comment: no words to thank you I have a long way to go it worked like charm

Comment: You're welcome. Just a vote and a checkmark is enough to express your thanks :)

Comment: the other link was also very helpful